# Use Google feed API in Google aps script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-feed-api

I would like to import [Google Feed API](https://developers.google.com/feed/v1/devguide) for javascript in a Google script.
It seam their is no 'Import' in google script. How could I load the API ?
I their an over way than using Python like their show us [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/rest/quickstart/js) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Google Feed API has been deprecated since December 2016 and may no longer work.

Comment: Ah, yes it's writen on the top, sorry for my inadvertence